# How is it possible to join the div for RamblingSoul and that for its description?

Tags: html, css

How is it possible to join the div for RamblingSoul and that for its description so that the green color in between is removed and the two divs join together..?

Slicing

```
<style type="text/css">
html,body{  
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

    }
div#wrapper{    
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        line-height:normal;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        background-color:#FF3;
        font-size:10px;
        line-height:1.5px;
    }

div#wrapper div#header{
        width:100%;
        height:30%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;

    }


div#wrapper div#body{
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        background-color:#096;
    }

div#wrapper div#footer{
        width:100%;
        height:20.0%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;

    }



div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo{
        width:25%;
        height:80%;
        //border:#000 thin dotted;
        border:#930 medium groove;
        //float:left;
        margin:0px ;

        background-color:#096;


    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hdesign{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        //float:left;
        margin:0px 250px;
    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hTestimonial{
        //width:40%;

        width:30%;
        height:100%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        float:right;

    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo div#Logoheader{
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#F6F;
        text-align:center;
        height:20px;
    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo div#Logodesc{
        font-size:10px;
        height:20px;
        background-color:#F90;

    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="hlogo">


                    <div id="Logoheader">RamblingSoul</div>
                    <div id="Logodesc">
                        <p> A Free CSS Template From </p>
                        <p>RamblingSoul</p>
                    </div>


        </div>
        <div id="hdesign">

        </div>
        <div id="hTestimonial">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
div#Logodesc>p:first-child
{
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Some other adjustments are also in order! Like the line-height: 1.5